# Add an enddate to my date field programmatically

Tags: 7, datetime

I'm using the [date field](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) contrib module and added it to my custom module which creates a content type and its fields.

I've successfully added a field(+instance) of date with a popupcalendar to my contenttype with a lot of help of [this comment](https://www.drupal.org/node/1082822#comment-4317270). But I can't figure out how to get the end date working. It's only showing a first date, not value2. I've tried screwing around in the field settings by adding `'enddate'=> 1` to no avail.

What setting should I use to get a start AND enddate to work in my field within my module?

Here are the fields I'm using(Its within a field collection which also works fine)

```
//Field collection
array(
    'field' => array(
        'field_name' => 'field_available_periods',
        'label' => $t('Available periods'),
        'cardinality' => -1,
        'type' => 'field_collection',
    ),
    'instance' => array(
        'field_name' => 'field_available_periods',
        'entity_type' => 'node',
        'bundle' => 'accommodation',
        'label' => $t('Available periods'),
        'description' => '',
        'widget' => array('type' => 'field_collection_embed'),
        'required' => 1,
    ),
),
array(
    'field' => array(
        'field_name' => 'field_van_tot',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'label' => $t('From - Until'),
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'settings' => array(
            'granularity' => array(
                'year' => 'year',
                'month' => 'month',
                'day' => 'day',
            ),
            'enddate' => 1,
        ),
    ),
    'instance' => array(
        'field_name' => 'field_van_tot',
        'entity_type' => 'field_collection_item',
        'bundle' => 'field_available_periods',
        'label' => $t('From - Until'),
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'description' => '',
        'required' => FALSE,
        'widget' => array(
            'type' => 'date_popup',
            'settings' => array (
                'input_format' => 'Y-m-d',
                'year_range' => '-0:+2',

            ),
        ),
        'display' => array('default' => array('type' => 'date_default')),
        'settings' => array(
            'default_value' => 'blank',
            'default_format' => 'short',
            'default_value_code' => '',
            'default_value2' => 'blank',
            'default_value_code2' => '',

        ),
    )
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it by changing the field settings' "todate":

```
'field' => array(
                'field_name' => 'field_van_tot',
                'type' => 'datetime',
                'label' => $t('From - Until'),
                'cardinality' => 1,
                'settings' => array(
                    'granularity' => array(
                        'year' => 'year',
                        'month' => 'month',
                        'day' => 'day',
                    ),
                    'todate' => 'required',
                ),
            ),
```